# Группировка по разности текущего и предыдущего элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Подскажите возможно ли произвести группировку по столбцу LAST, отобрать значения в группу с разницей <=10.

Пробовал таким способом, но отрабатывает каждое значение в фрэйме:

```
df.groupby('<LAST>', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: df[df['<LAST>'].diff() <= 10])
```

Входные данные:

```
      <LAST>   <VOL>  <SIZE>
0   141770.0    2065    928
1   141780.0    2564    1180
2   141790.0    2217    1040
3   141800.0    2924    1124
4   142350.0    1973    926
5   142360.0    1968    914
6   142380.0    1711    945
7   142390.0    2038    936
8   142400.0    2245    974
9   142410.0    1826    989
10  142820.0    1899    1009
11  142830.0    2992    1167
12  142840.0    2539    1248
13  142850.0    2772    1169
14  142860.0    1930    933
```

Необходимо получить что-то вроде, что бы можно было производить операции по каждой группе отдельно:

```
      <LAST>   <VOL>  <SIZE>
1   141770.0    2065    928
    141780.0    2564    1180
    141790.0    2217    1040
    141800.0    2924    1124
2   142350.0    1973    926
    142360.0    1968    914
3   142380.0    1711    945
    142390.0    2038    936
    142400.0    2245    974
    142410.0    1826    989
4   142820.0    1899    1009
    142830.0    2992    1167
    142840.0    2539    1248
    142850.0    2772    1169
    142860.0    1930    933
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких случаях обычно используют трюк с методом `.cumsum()`, который применяют к последовательности булевых значений, как показано в ответе @splash58.

Как это работает пошагово:

```
In [75]: df["<LAST>"].diff()
Out[75]:
0       NaN
1      10.0
2      10.0
3      10.0
4     550.0
5      10.0
6      20.0
7      10.0
8      10.0
9      10.0
10    410.0
11     10.0
12     10.0
13     10.0
14     10.0
Name: <LAST>, dtype: float64
```

теперь применяем логическое отрицание - это нужно потому что значение `False` представлено в Python нулем и кумулятивная сумма для группы не будет изменяться. Т.е. нам надо получить такую последовательность `True` / `False`, для которой `True` будет стоять только в начале каждой группы.

```
In [76]: df["<LAST>"].diff().gt(10)
Out[76]:
0     False   # <--- начало группы 0 (сумма всех элементов 0-ой группы будет равна 0)
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True   # <--- начало группы 1
5     False
6      True   # <--- начало группы 2
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True   # <--- начало группы 3
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
Name: <LAST>, dtype: bool
```

осталось только применить метод кумулятивной суммы:

```
In [77]: df["<LAST>"].diff().gt(10).cumsum()
Out[77]:
0     0
1     0    # False + False = 0
2     0    # False + False + False = 0
3     0    # False + False + False + False = 0
4     1    # (False + False + False + False) + True = 1
5     1    # (False + False + False + False) + True + False= 1
6     2    # (False + False + False + False) + (True + False) + True = 2
7     2    # ...
8     2
9     2
10    3
11    3
12    3
13    3
14    3
Name: <LAST>, dtype: int32
```

В последнем шаге мы фактически получили номера нужных нам групп.

Теперь по этому номеру группы можно сделать группировку:

```
In [78]: df.groupby(df["<LAST>"].diff().gt(10).cumsum()).groups
Out[78]:
{0: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64'),
 1: Int64Index([4, 5], dtype='int64'),
 2: Int64Index([6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64'),
 3: Int64Index([10, 11, 12, 13, 14], dtype='int64')}
```

атрибут `.groups` возвращает словарь с индексами элементов групп.

Comment: все время забываю про diff. Почему он у меня в голове не держится :)

Comment: Спасибо! Это большие знания!

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, то что у вас показано в вопросе - это группировка по точкам, когда разница с предыдущим больше 10. Это можно сделать используя метод cumsum(). Я вам подставил в apply код, который просто показывает группы, но вы можете использовать свою функцию обработки или встроенные агрегатные методы

```
df.groupby((df['<LAST>'].sub(df.shift()['<LAST>'])).gt(10).cumsum()) \
  .apply(lambda x: x.assign())

             <LAST>  <VOL>  <SIZE>
<LAST>                            
0      0   141770.0   2065     928
       1   141780.0   2564    1180
       2   141790.0   2217    1040
       3   141800.0   2924    1124
1      4   142350.0   1973     926
       5   142360.0   1968     914
2      6   142380.0   1711     945
       7   142390.0   2038     936
       8   142400.0   2245     974
       9   142410.0   1826     989
3      10  142820.0   1899    1009
       11  142830.0   2992    1167
       12  142840.0   2539    1248
       13  142850.0   2772    1169
       14  142860.0   1930     933
```